# How to view data from database haskell

Tags: haskell

I have table in haskell database. My 'link_des' table has two columns. I want to view both columns (data only) at the same time. My code is:

```
printURLs :: IO ()
printURLs = do urls <- getURLs
           mapM_ print urls

getURLs :: IO [String]
getURLs = do conn <- connectSqlite3 "database.db"
         res <- quickQuery' conn "SELECT * FROM link_des" []
         return $ map fromSql (map head res)
```

With this I am getting first column data like

> ["col_1_data_1","col_1_data_2", ...]

using 'last' in lieu of 'head'  I can get

> ["col_2_data_1","col_2_data_2", ...]

But I want to get data like

> [("col_1_data_1","col_2_data_1"),("col_1_data_2","col_2_data_2"), ...]

which is actually like the pattern [(row_1),(row_2), ...]

Can anyone please help me. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried to implement this yourself?  It looks like you want a tuple, could you use a function like `f [x, y] = (x, y)`?  Be warned that if the list is too long or too short, you could end up with an error, you'll have to worry about handling that case.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the type signature of quickQuery', you will see that it returns type IO [[SqlValue]].  That means that you already have the data in a form very similar to what you want....  Instead of

```
[("col_1_data_1","col_2_data_1"),("col_1_data_2","col_2_data_2"), ...]
```

you have

```
[["col_1_data_1","col_2_data_1"],["col_1_data_2","col_2_data_2"], ...]
```

The function you wrote is just pulling out the first column of this using "map head".

You could always write some code to convert a table with a known number of columns and types to the corresponding tuples (using a function like "convert [first, second] = (fromSql first, fromSql second)"), but it is much harder to write something that does this for arbitrary tables with differing number of columns and types.  There are two reasons this is so....

a. First, you need to turn a list into a tuple, which isn't possible in Haskell for lists of differing sizes unless you use extensions.  The main problem is that each size of tuple is its own type, and a single function can't choose its output type based on the input.  You can do some trickery using GHC extensions, but the result is probably more complicated that you probably want to get into.

b. Second, You have to convert each value in the result from SqlValue to the appropriate Haskell type.  This is also hard for similar reasons.

You might want to consider another approach altogether....  Take a look at the Yesod persistent database library, which is described at http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent.  With that you define your schema in a quasiquote, and it creates Haskell records that are completely type safe.

Comment: "you need to turn a list into a tuple, which isn't possible in Haskell unless you use extensions".  `f [x, y] = Just (x, y); f _ = Nothing`.  Didn't need a single extension for that one...  But you are correct in saying that you can't write a single function to turn a list into an equivalently sized tuple for all lists.  However, you _can_ validate your data returned from the sql query, which should be in a structured form, and convert that to your Haskell data type.  The same goes in any other language when talking to a DB, you make a query, validate the data, and convert to your type.

Comment: @bheklilr- Sorry, my wording was sloppy....  I definitely meant to write what you said, of course you can write these functions as a one off for a particular known database, but not in the general case unless you use extensions.  I'll clean it up above.  Yesod persistence basically offers a way to automatically write the particular functions to do this conversion (not to a tuple though).